# On mobius and Dirichlet type transformation of complex valued functions on $[1,\infty )$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

For $f : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb C$, it is known that $g(x)= \sum_{1\le n \le x, n \in \mathbb N} f(x/n), \forall x \in [1,\infty)$ iff $f(x)=\sum_{1\le n \le x, n \in \mathbb N} \mu(n) g(x/n), \forall x \in [1,\infty)$ .

So if we define $\widehat f(x):=\sum_{1\le n \le x, n \in \mathbb N} f(x/n)$ and $\check f(x):=\sum_{1\le n \le x, n \in \mathbb N} \mu(n) f(x/n)$, then $f=\widehat{\check f}=\check {\widehat f}$ .

My question is : Let $f : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb C$ be a not identically zero function; then can both $f$ and $\widehat f$ have compact support ? If this is possible, my next question would be , is it possible that one of $f, \widehat f$ has finite support and the other compact support ?

If $supp (f) \subseteq \mathbb N$ then I can show that both $supp (f)$ and $supp(\widehat f)$ cannot be compact i.e. cannot be finite (compact subsets of the subspace $\mathbb N$ are finite) ; but I am unable to see what happens in general . Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @reuns : what's $h$ ? And how does $H$ help ?

Comment: I meant $f(e^u)1_{u > 0} = h(u)1_{u > 0}$

Comment: @reuns: you should also mention $supp (h) \subseteq [0,\infty)$

Comment: @reuns: Okay, so your definition of $h$ and $H$, we have $H(u)=\widehat f(e^u), \forall u\ge 0$ ... so what ?

Comment: @reuns: Hello ... you there ? Do you care to write a well-explained answer ?